# Ошибка callback_data в inline-меню aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Доброй ночи. Хочу в своем боте ловить одним хэндлером callback_data из inline-кнопок одной клавиатуры, а не по отдельности в каждом хэндлере.

Создал фабрику:

```py
cb = CallbackData('keyboard', 'action')
```

Создал клавиатуру:

```py
kb = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 1", callback_data='filter1')
kb2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 2", callback_data=cb.new('filter2'))
kb3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 3", callback_data=cb.new('filter3'))
kb4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 4", callback_data=cb.new('filter4'))
kb5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 5", callback_data=cb.new('filter5'))
kb6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 6", callback_data=cb.new('filter6'))
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
keyboard.add(kb, kb2, kb3, kb4, kb5, kb6)
await callback.message.edit_caption(caption="Клавиатура", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Создал хэндлер:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(cb.filter())
async def process_callback_kb1btn1(callback: types.CallbackQuery, сallback_data: dict):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 1", callback_data=cb.new('filter1'))
    kb2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 2", callback_data=cb.new('filter2'))
    kb3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 3", callback_data=cb.new('filter3'))
    kb4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 4", callback_data=cb.new('filter4'))
    kb5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 5", callback_data=cb.new('filter5'))
    kb6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фильтр 6", callback_data=cb.new('filter6'))
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard.add(kb, kb2, kb3, kb4, kb5, kb6)
    if callback_data['action'] == 'filter1':
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Проверка')
```

Ловлю ошибку при нажатии на кнопку:

> TypeError: process_callback_kb1btn1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'сallback_data'

Comment: потому что в функции process_callback_kb1btn1 вы используете аргумент сallback_data, но не передаете его при вызове

Comment: попробуй удалить аргумент `сallback_data: dict`